# Scheme define a constructor and selectors for a matrix object

Tags: scheme, r5rs

I'm trying to develop a constructor and selectors for a simple 2x2 matrix but I'm unsure if what I've made is correct.  This takes a list with 4 elements and makes a 2x2:

```
(define matrix2x2
  (lambda (list)

    (define to-list list) ;returns the list form of this matrix
    (define get-place ;returns a place based on input row col
      (lambda (row col)
        (cond ((and (equal? row 1) (equal? col 1)) (car list))
              ((and (equal? row 1) (equal? col 2)) (car (cdr list)))
              ((and (equal? row 2) (equal? col 1)) (car (cdr (cdr list))))
              ((and (equal? row 2) (equal? col 2)) (car (cdr (cdr (cdr list)))))
              (else (display "no such place")))))

    (lambda (ret)
      (cond ((eq? ret 'get-place) get-place)
            ((eq? ret 'to-list) to-list)
            (else (error "Unknown request" ret))))))

;tests
(define my-matrix (m2x2 '(8 1 2 7)))
((my-matrix 'get-place) 2 2)
(my-matrix 'to-list)
```

This works... but I'm not sure I'm using selectors properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is the "usual" Scheme way of implementing objects via closures.  You could of course go on to define some convenience functions for the selectors:

```
(define (get-place matrix ix) ((matrix 'get-place) ix)
(define (matrix->list matrix) ...)
```

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking about the "proper" use of selectors.  After all, you already know that it works ...

Comment: Thanks Fixnum.  I guess I just wanted some reassurance on this.  The SICP book is kind of vague with this term (pg 83 ed. 2).  It says "The interface between these two parts (concrete data representation and the data itself) of our system will be a set of procedures, called selectors and constructors, that implement the abstract data in terms of concrete representation".  After that the term "selector" is not mentioned again...  So it made me a bit unsure of this term.  Thanks again.

Comment: As you'll see from SICP (though it's standard notation), a "constructor" bundles some data together into a closure/structure/record/object/datatype, whereas a "selector" gets some data back out again.  So here the `matrix2x2` is the constructor and the functions `(m 'get-place)` (or `get-place`) and `(mat 'to-list)` (or `matrix->list`) are the selectors.  If it's still unclear, there's plenty of other examples in that chapter of the book.  HTH.